# Como exibir os elementos de um array sendo que eles são arrays?

Tags: php

Criei um array em que cada índice armazena outro array - ambos globais para que os valores não sejam apagados. O problema está em exibir cada elemento, quando tento, o PHP me retorna "Notice: Array to string conversion"

Código:

```
function cadastrar($nome, $raca, $cor, $tipoPelo){

    $_SESSION['array1'][] = array($nome, $raca, $cor, $tipoPelo);

    $_SESSION['array2'][] = $_SESSION['array1'];


}

function listar(){



    for($i = 0; $i < sizeof($_SESSION['array2']); $i++){
        echo $_SESSION['array2'][$i];
    }

}
```

Com o var_dump($_SESSION['array2']); exibe:

```
  Arrayarray(3) { [0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" } } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "nome1" [1]=> string(5) "raca1" [2]=> string(4) "cor1" [3]=> string(5) "tipo1" } } [2]=> array(3) { [0]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(0) "" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" } [1]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "nome1" [1]=> string(5) "raca1" [2]=> string(4) "cor1" [3]=> string(5) "tipo1" } [2]=> array(4) { [0]=> string(5) "nome2" [1]=> string(6) "raça2" [2]=> string(4) "cor2" [3]=> string(5) "tipo2" } } }
```

Comment: faz assim, no listar da um `var_dump($_SESSION['array2'])` e edita a questão com o resultado.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que entendi, você quer armazenar em uma sessão diversos cadastros feitos. Se for isso você pode fazer algo do tipo

```
function cadastrar($nome, $raca, $cor, $tipoPelo){
    // Verifica se a $_SESSION['dados_cadastro'] existe, caso nao exista, cria um array vazio, caso exista pega o valor e coloca na variabel $dados_cadastro
    $dados_cadastro = isset($_SESSION['dados_cadastro'])?$_SESSION['dados_cadastro']:[];

    // Adiciona no array $dados_cadastro os novos dados enviados
    array_push($dados_cadastro, [$nome, $raca, $cor, $tipoPelo]);

    // Atualiza a $_SESSION['dados_cadastro'] com os dados de todos os cadastros
    $_SESSION['dados_cadastro'] = $dados_cadastro;
}

function listar(){

    // Verifica se a $_SESSION['dados_cadastro'] existe, caso não, informa que nao tem dados
    if(!isset($_SESSION['dados_cadastro'])){
        echo 'Nenhum item cadastrado';
    }else{
        // Faz um loop em todos os dados em $_SESSION['dados_cadastro'] e imprime na tela
        foreach($_SESSION['dados_cadastro'] as $cadastro){
            var_dump('<pre>');
            var_dump($cadastro);
            var_dump('</pre>');
       }
    }
}
```

Adicionamos 3 cadastros em **$_SESSION['dados_cadastro']**

```
cadastrar('nome 1', 'raca 1', 'cor 1', 'tipo_pelo 1');
cadastrar('nome 2', 'raca 2', 'cor 2', 'tipo_pelo 2');
cadastrar('nome 3', 'raca 3', 'cor 3', 'tipo_pelo 3');
```

Ao chamar listar, veremos tudo que tem nessa variável de sessão

```
listar();
```

E a saída será

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "nome 1"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "raca 1"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "cor 1"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "tipo_pelo 1"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "nome 2"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "raca 2"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "cor 2"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "tipo_pelo 2"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "nome 3"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "raca 3"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "cor 3"
  [3]=>
  string(11) "tipo_pelo 3"
}
```

Comment: Sim, quero exibir os elementos do vetor, mas de uma forma que eu possa manipulá-los e sem a exibição dos índices e demais informações que sejam desnecessárias ao usuário leigo que vai acessar a aplicação.

Comment: Então, ali dentro do loop, você pode manipular as informações da forma que quiser,  como em uma tabela, pro exemplo. Eu só dei o dump para mostrar o que foi armazenado.

Answer (score 1):

Isso está acontecendo com você por que você criou um array dentro de um array.

Se você retirar o `[]` de `$_SESSION['array1']` e `$_SESSION['array2']` ira funcionar corretamente.

**Exemplo:**

```
function cadastrar($nome, $raca, $cor, $tipoPelo){
    $_SESSION['array1'] = array($nome, $raca, $cor, $tipoPelo);
    $_SESSION['array2'] = $_SESSION['array1'];
}

function listar(){
   cadastrar('teste','teste1','teste2','teste3');
   foreach ($_SESSION['array1'] as $value)
      echo $value . ' ';
}
listar();
```

Comment: Tentei aqui mas ao retirar os colchetes a variável só armazena o último valor inserido, eu preciso que tudo o que for entrado seja exibido. Por isso utilizei um array para guardar outros arrays, eles vão funcionar como um "banco de dados".

Comment: Infelizmente exibe apenas um grupo de valores. Se eu adicionar novos valores os anteriores desaparecem.

Comment: Conseguiu alterar?

Answer (score 1):

Basta colocar outro loop dentro do primeiro:

```
foreach($_SESSION['array2'] as $item){
    foreach($item as $subitem){
        echo $subitem;
    }
}
```

Usei o `foreach` por ser mais simples, mas pode fazer com o `for` também

Comment: Testei aqui mas o mesmo erro aparece.

Answer (score 1):

Há uma estrutura de repetição conhecida por iterar arrays ou objetos que é o `foreach`.

Exemplo de como é o seu uso:

```
$array = Array("maça","banana","uva");
foreach ($array as $elemento) {
    echo $elemento."<br>";
}
```

Saida:

```
maça
banana
uva
```

O primeiro parâmetro é o array que queremos percorrer o segundo é a variavel a qual vai ser atribuída o valor de um elemento do array

---

Para ajudar no seu problema você pode fazer dessa forma:

```
foreach($array as $elemento){
    if(!is_array($elemento)){
        echo $elemento;
    } else {
        foreach($elemento as $elemento) echo $elemento;
    }
}
```

Ele vai iterar dentro do foreach e verificar com o `is_array` se o elemento é um array, se não for ele vai executar o echo, se for ele vai iterar aquele array.

Fica a dica dar uma olha na documentação do PHP, tá ai o link para tirar suas duvidas sobre o
[Foreach](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)